# Pressing toggle button on webpage in Java using Htmlunit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

So I have basically been stuck on a particular piece of code for a few days now. I am trying to go to a webpage and click a specific toggle button using Htmlunit in Java.

The code I currently have for the java program:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("webpage URL"); 
page1.getElementById("additional_parameters_toggle").click();
```

The HTML code for the webpage toggle:

```
<div class="parameters clearfix">
<input type="checkbox" id="additional_parameters">
<label for="additional_parameters class="additional_parameters_toggle" data-name="big old ugly toggle">
    <span class = "checkbox_outer">
        <span class = "checkbox_inner"></span>
    </span>
<span class="label_text">Show details / hourly data</span>
</label>
</div>
```

I figured that should work but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. If there is anyone that could offer some insight or help in anyway, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom has hinted, `.getElementById()` will not work since there is no `id` HTML attribute of that value.

You need to use:

```
page1.<HtmlElement>getFirstByXPath("//label[@class='additional_parameters_toggle']").click();
```

which means, find the first element by XPath: search for any `label` with a `class` attributes of "additional_parameters_toggle", then `.click()` it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the job perfectly! I can't thank you and Tom enough for the help! Hope you both have a great day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
page1.getElementById("additional_parameters_toggle")
```

Looks like you don't have an element having this value as an Id.  You do however have an element with an attribute `class` containing this value.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I don't quite follow you. There are 3 attributes that have class attributes.

Comment: You're using getElementById with a value additional_parameters_toggle.  In the HTML sample you provide there is no HTMLelement with this as its Id